# symmetrical dilatations in all directions

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus

In Albert Einstein's "The Meaning of Relativity" first chapter titled "SPACE AND TIME IN PRE-RELATIVITY PHYSICS" he says:

"For physical reasons (no slipping) it is assumed that for symmetrical dilatations in all directions, i.e. when
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}
=
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}
=
\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3}
\qquad
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}
=
\ldots
= 0, 
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
there are no frictional forces present, from which it follows that $\beta = -\frac{2}{3} \alpha$."

My two questions are:

1. What is a symmetrical dilatation in all directions?
2. Why would equation (1) be an example of a symmetrical dilatation in all directions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that that is a definition of symmetrical dilatations, and Einstein is saying “if we assume that this special form of $u_i$ must produce a degenerate stress-energy tensor the only way that can happen is if these two arbitrary linear parameters are not actually arbitrary, and instead one is two thirds of the other, to force this cancellation.”

As for what symmetry this has, I would expect that the cross derivatives being zero means we are talking about $$[u_x, ~u_y,~ u_z] = [a(x),~b(y),~c(z)],$$
and the restriction $a'(x) = b'(y) = c'(z)$ would seem to force all three derivatives to be constant with respect to $x,y,z$, say some constant $\lambda$. Adding some constants of integration $c_{x,y,z}$ we would find that $$\vec u = \vec c + \lambda \vec r,$$ so the flow fields being considered can also be described as affine transformations of the position vector. If $\lambda\ne 0$ we can also write this as $$\vec u = \lambda (\vec r - \vec r_0),$$ so we are talking about either constant flow fields $\lambda =0$ or flow fields which are scaled position vectors relative to some origin, being in some sense the flow you would get if the fluid was rubber being stretched uniformly in all directions, or so.

Comment: Thanks CR Drost. I thought equations (1) was only an example of a symmetrical dilatation in all directions. If you had to give a definition of a symmetrical dilitation in all directions what would it be? if you were to say you would use equation (1) as the definition do you mean that it would apply in all space or only at one point?

Comment: Well I would say that he's talking specifically about a fluid flow and so it is reasonable to take the very last equation as the definition.

Comment: With that said the first one has the nice property that you could probably extend the definition to a manifold, $U$ is a symmetrical dilatation if $\nabla_V U = \alpha V$ or so. But Einstein is just saying, “we need this expression to be symmetric and in the easiest case it is linear; here is the most general linear symmetric expression ... But actually we can constrain this more because in this special case we know there is no friction, so this expression must be zero, so these constants must occur in exactly these proportions ... and in this other case we know this constant is viscosity.”

Answer (score 1):

CR Drost's answer is correct already. I am only adding a simpler perspective here, in regard to pre-relativity fluid mechanics.

> What is a symmetrical dilatation in all directions?

It is isotropic expansion (or contraction). A sphere undergoing symmetrical dilatation would remain spherical at all times (only its size would change).

> Why would equation (1) be an example of a symmetrical dilatation in all directions?

It is not merely an example, but it is the equation that isotropic expansion must obey. Consider a spherical fluid element whose radius is $\delta r$, in the reference frame in which the sphere's centre is at rest. Establish a Cartesian coordinate system whose origin coincides with the sphere centre. Because the sphere is undergoing isotropic expansion, the velocity of a point on the sphere's surface is everywhere radially outward and has the same magnitude at all points on the sphere's surface. In particular this means that along X-axis the velocity is directed entirely along X-axis, and similarly for Y and Z axis.

Since the sphere's centre is at rest, $(\partial u_1/\partial x_1)\delta r$ gives the magnitude of velocity of the point on sphere's surface along X-axis, $(\partial u_2/\partial x_2)\delta r$ gives the magnitude of velocity of the point on sphere's surface along Y-axis, and $(\partial u_3/\partial x_3)\delta r$ gives the magnitude of velocity of the point on sphere's surface along Z-axis (subscripts 1,2,3, stand for components along X,Y,Z, axes respectively). For isotropic expansion they are equal, which gives: $(\partial u_1/\partial x_1)=(\partial u_2/\partial x_2)=(\partial u_3/\partial x_3)=\lambda$ (say). Further Y and Z component of velocity is zero for a point on the sphere's surface along X-axis: $(\partial u_2/\partial x_1)\delta r=0=(\partial u_3/\partial x_1)\delta r$. In general, $(\partial u_i/\partial x_j)\delta r=0$ if $i\neq j$. In summary the velocity gradient tensor is a multiple of the identity tensor:
$$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}&0&0\\ 0&\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}&0\\ 0&0&\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x_3} \end{bmatrix}=\lambda \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
which makes sense because identity tensor is the only second order tensor which is isotropic (every vector, irrespective of its direction, is an eigenvector of the identity tensor). $\lambda$ is the rate of expansion at a point.

Comment: thank you @Deep for adding a simpler perspective here. I need to slow down and take this answer one step at a time.

Comment: thank you @Deep for adding a simpler perspective here. I need to slow down and take this answer one step at a time. I am new on this site so please excuse my poor ability to format this response. In your specific example of an expanding sphere I have a problem understanding. The partial derivatives that you give as being equal like partial u1 by partial x1 and partial u2 by partial x2 are equal in your example but you are measuring them at different points in space!! I thought they would have to be equal at the same point in space.

Comment: @davetrouble The partial derivatives are all evaluated at the centre of the sphere. What I have done is a Taylor expansion of velocity $u$ about the sphere centre in the small parameter $\delta r$. Thus along X-axis: $u(\delta r)=u(0)+(\partial u/\partial x)|_{\delta r=0}\delta r+\ldots$, and $u(0)=0$. Similarly for velocity components $v(\delta r),w(\delta r),$ along $Y,Z,$ axes. I equate $u(\delta r)=v(\delta r)=w(\delta r)$ and take the limit $\delta r\to 0$.

Comment: @davetrouble Also note that if you take the gradient of the equation in CR Drost's answer you get: $\nabla(\vec{u}=\lambda(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0))\Rightarrow\nabla\vec{u}=\lambda \mathbf{I}$, because $\nabla\vec{r}=\mathbf{I}$, in which $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity tensor (you may verify this using indicial notation). Thus what I have derived is the same formula as CR Drost's.

Comment: Ok, i think i understand your example of a symmetical dilitation in all directions. It seems you are suggesting a flow spherically outward from the origin (0,0,0). u1(0,0,0)=u2(0,0,0)=u3(0,0,0)=0; partial u1 by x1 at (0,0,0) = partial u2 by x2 at (0,0,0)=partial u3 by x3 at (0,0,0); partial u1 by x2 at (0,0,0) = ...=0. So do you think Einstein was talking about a symmetrical dilatation in all directions as only taking place at a single point? For some reason, when i read it, i thought he was talking about a flow which would be a symmetrical dilatation in all directions at all points?

Comment: @davetrouble Specifying the distribution of symmetrical-dilatation over space is up to you; in other words, rate of expansion $\lambda$ is a scalar field over the space. So you can indeed have "a flow which would be a symmetrical dilatation in all directions at all points" which amounts to a particular specification of $\lambda$ field. I can't locate Einstein's book (I had a copy and I have read it, but long ago), so I am not sure what Einstein meant; also I don't have expertise enough in relativity theory, so I doubt I could answer your question in the context of relativity satisfactorily.

Comment: this question has only to do with his 1st chapter "space and time in PRE-relativity physics" so does not require any relativity theory. if i'm not mistaken your example only satisfies equations (1) at the origin. once you move away from the origin you will not have partial u1 by x1 = partial u2 by x2 = partial u3 by x3. so i don't think your example would be a symmetrical dilatation in all directions at all points. the book is available online at "the project gutenberg". maybe it's good enough for einstein's argument  to have it at a single point?